# MongoDB index size

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with half billion of records. Every second inserting avg 100 docs on it. It has index on datetime field, which size about 5 GB.

```
"created" : ISODate("2020-01-01T12:48:51.671Z")
```

So, quection is - if I create field of value of rounded datetime by minute, will it use less storage for this index?

I mean, every record will have field with value, for eg:

```
"created" : ISODate("2020-01-01T12:48:00Z")
```

UPDATED:

I tested in collection with about 20m docs. Results:

```
        "_id_" : 221757440,
        "created" : 210997248,
        "created_rounded" : 97366016
```

Comment: Create a random collection and a large set of documents, and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer, YES!

The format of [Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#date) in the mongoDb is constant and no matter how much data you want to put in. The allocated memory is not changing.

> BSON Date is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970).

UPDATE:

The indexes are something like {key1: [value1, value2]}. Then if you round the date field that you mentioned, it will create less `key` and in the end, your answer is **YES**.

Comment: I mean, will the index size depends on the count of equal values. If there will be thoundes of values of e.g. 020-01-01T12:48:***Z, or one of 020-01-01T12:48:00Z ?

Comment: @Alexey Yes, your index size will be decreased.

Comment: @Alexey The ObjectId that use as the primary key also contains a timestamp. It was not part of your question but thought maybe it be helpful to mention.

Comment: The index still needs to store pointers to each document indexed.

Comment: Sure, but if you had 1-1 key-index, it will be more than the rounded time. @D.SM

Comment: I tested on test collection, results in question